# Kentico 9 Web Farm Synchronization

Tags: synchronization, kentico, web-farm

Our team of developers is investigating an issue in Kentico 9 that relates to web farm servers. Initially we wanted to check web farm synchronization as it may be related to another issue experienced with smart search index. Then we found out that to use web farm synchronization, all its servers need to be registered and configured in the system. Kentico CMS for this application is running on Microsoft Azure and according to Kentico, this means that automatic web farm mode is enabled by default.

Both web farm servers have a status of “Healthy” when we check it in Kentico.
[image: Image 1]

However, if we check the ‘Tasks’ tab we can see the following error message:
[image: Image 2]

The servers and machine names also seem to have been swapped. Not sure this is completely related to the issue but thought it could have something to do with it.
In my understanding server A should have a machine named with the same server name, in this case, A as well. But it does not, its machine name is the same as server B. See image below for more details.
[image: Image 3]

Has anybody ever seen an error such as the above? What is it related to and what needs to be done?
In addition, what is ‘UPDATEBIZFORMFILE’ under the Type tab?

Comment: What is the Azure Web app configuration? Are the instances using the same, shared file system? If yes, you may want to disable sync of physical files like smart search indexes, form files and so on to avoid access conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few [known issues](https://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes) with web farms in version 9. Highly suggested to upgrade to a newer version (at least version 11) as that's really the only way to resolve the problem.